# Cakephp 3 - Convert sql query to cakephp find

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I'm new to **CakePHP 3..** and don't really know how to convert this *SQL query -> CakePHP* find thinghy.

```
 SELECT categories_competences_cvs.cv_id, 
                             categories_competences_vacancies.vacancy_id
     FROM categories_competences
     INNER JOIN categories_competences_cvs ON 
       categories_competences.id = 
                        categories_competences_cvs.categories_competence_id
     INNER JOIN categories_competences_vacancies ON 
       categories_competences_cvs.categories_competence_id = 
                        categories_competences_vacancies.categories_competence_id
     INNER JOIN categories ON 
       categories_competences.category_id = categories.id
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is simply asking for someone to write their code for them.

Answer (score 2):

There is very complete documentation available for how to retrieve data using CakePHP.

You can either use raw SQL:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html

Or you can use the query builder:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

CakePHP is an MVC framework and in order to get a better understanding of how to retrieve data using an MVC framework, I would suggest going through the quick start guide (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html) as a first step.